# Deleting elements from a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In a matrix, to remove the columns in which the element of the first line is 0, we can use:

```
ind2remove = (A(1,:) == 0);
A(:,ind2remove) = [];
```

How do I do that if `A` is a cell? I want to remove the columns in which the element of the first row is 0.

I tried:

```
ind2remove = (A{1,:} == 0);
A{:,ind2remove} = [];
```

but I got the error message:

```
??? Error using ==> eq
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> ind2remove = (A{1,:} == 0);
```

Comment: A cell can hold different data types. How does your cell look like? Does it just have a single element (numeric) in each cell? The answer is simple, but I'd like an example data.

Comment: @yoda: the first row of the cell A contains numeric values, and the second line contains matrices

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indexing using `{ }` gives you the *contents* of the cell, whereas indexing using `( )` returns the same type as the original object i.e., if `A` is a cell, `A{i,j}` will return what it's holding, and `A(i,j)` will always return a cell. You need the latter.

So in your case, you can do the following to eliminate all columns where the first row has a `0`.

```
A(:, cellfun(@(x)x==0, A(1,:))) = [];
```

The assumption here is that each cell in the first row holds only a single numeric element, as per your comment.